# pygame in anaconda unable to install

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda

Can't install python on anaconda using:

`conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2`

> Error:
>   PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
>
> - pygame 1.9.2*

Any Ideas?

I have anaconda 3 and win 7(x64)

Comment: you can not install python on anaconda? or you can not install pygame on anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

The channel you referenced [tlatorre](https://anaconda.org/tlatorre/pygame) does not contain a windows version of pygame, only linux.

You can find a windows version in the [cogsci channel](https://anaconda.org/cogsci/pygame), and can be installed with:

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```